# Probailty of Ygreater than or equal to X^2

Tags: probability, bivariate

I want to solve the below mentioned question which involve transformation or change of variable technique

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGmwg.png]

Comment: It would be useful to see that $P(Y \geq X^{2}) = P (X^{2} - Y \leq 0)$ and let $g: (x,y) \mapsto x^{2} - y$.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to draw the region to understand it better as I describe. The region is in the first quadrant, between the lines $x+y=1$ and $x+y=2$. So, it's like a strip. It's your PDF's support. Then, for $P(Y\geq X^2)$ we sketch the curve $y=x^2$, and integrate the joint PDF in the strip where points are above $y=x^2$. The parabola intersects with the lines at two points (ignoring negative roots): $x+x^2=1\rightarrow x=\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{2}=x_1$ and $x+x^2=2\rightarrow x=1$.

If $x\in[0,x_1]$, we enter the region from the below line and exit from the upper line and so integrate from $y=1-x\rightarrow y=2-x$. If $x\in [x_1,1]$, we enter the region from the parabola, but exit it from the upper line, i.e. $y=x^2\rightarrow y=2-x$, yielding the final formulation:
$$P(Y\geq X^2)=\int_{0}^{x_1}\int_{1-x}^{2-x}{\frac{6x}{7}dydx}+\int_{x_1}^1\int_{x^2}^{2-x}\frac{6x}{7}dydx$$
which is for you to solve.